# React-router-dom v6 didn't show page when try to route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-router-dom

Hi guys so I'm trying to learn about react-router-dom newest version which is version 6. I tried to create a basic routing in my react-django app, but it didn't work if I create many Routes, for example when i change my route into 8000/product it will show page not found. Can anyone help me with it ?

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import Product from "./components/Product";
import ProductDetail from "./components/ProductDetail"

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
          <Route path="/product" element={<Product/>}/>
          <Route path="/productdetail" element={<ProductDetail/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      
      <Outlet/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You don't have any route paths that would match `"/8000/product"`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do. Can you clarify the issue and what you are expecting?

Comment: 8000 here means local host i think

Comment: yeah, its the local host

Comment: I see. And is your app running locally on port 8000?

Comment: for the "/" path it show perfectly just fine, i wanted to change the url for my local host into /products but when i change the url it shows error which is "page not found" The current path, product, didn’t match any of these.

And yeah it run on port 8000

Comment: try removing the outlet and see if it works

Comment: Does it work if you navigate to `"/product"` instead of reloading the app via the address bar?

Comment: it only work if I replace my "/" element with either <Product/> or <ProductDetail/>

Comment: Did you try navigating to the other routes? Not change the URL in the address bar. Not replace the "/" path with other components, but navigate to the other paths?

Comment: No I haven't try that.

Comment: everything in the code above is fine and I just double-checked it.

Comment: This seems more like a server configuration issue. I'm unfamiliar with django, but tagged your question. I think you just need to configure the server to bounce the sub-routes to the root index.html file so the app loads and the router handles the sub-routes.

Comment: oh I see, thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the paths in your backend urlpatterns? It goes something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path ('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index. html' )), 
   path ('productdetail/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index.html')),
   path ('products/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index.html')),
]
```

Also rember for this to work you must have set the `TEMPLATE` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` arrys to point to your react application /build and /build/statics directory respectively.

Comment: Oh i see, that's why it's not working.. I didn't set the urlpatterns. Thank you very much. but what if I wanted to use path="*" for page that not included in our web, like not found page. how should i set the url patterns ?

Comment: When it comes to pages not included in a web I leave them to my backed because when I set DEBUG=FALSE when using django all those request will return a 404 page not found.